# Hide column based on column value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to hide columns which have value 0 in say row 5.

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work.

```
function myFunction() {
 
}
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 
  for(i=1 ; i<=lastColumn ; i++){
    var status = sheet.getRange(5+i).getValue(); //change "5" to desired column
    if (status == "0"){//change "0" to desired text
      sheet.hideColumns(i);//hide row if true
    }  
    else{
      sheet.showColumns(i);//unhide row if false
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error

> Exception: Range not found at onEdit(Copy of Best:10:24)

Any suggestions?

Comment: whats error , is loop going in if condtiion ? (did you tried adding a alert or console log in if condition) ?

Comment: This is the error     Exception: Range not found
    at onEdit(Copy of Best:10:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you are not using get range function correctly.

```
getRange(a1Notation) -- As per doc this a1Notation is string like A1 , A2 ..
```

and you are passing a integer. or if you know column change it to   (A or B as per need)

```
getRange( 'A' + (5 + i))
```

I guess you need to check other implementation of getRange that fullfill your need.

Please check

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation

[EDIT]

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 
  for(i=1 ; i<=lastColumn ; i++){
    var status = sheet.getRange(5,i).getValues(); //.getValue(); //change "5" to desired column
    if (status == "0"){//change "0" to desired text
      sheet.hideColumns(i);//hide row if true
    }  
    else{
      sheet.showColumns(i);//unhide row if false
    }
  }
}
```

this script will hide all the  column  in row 5  -- have values 0.

Comment: I am actually new to this

The values my script is looking for will be in D5:O5, when it finds 0 I want it to hide all the columns that have 0 and only display columns that have value 1. If the value changes from 0 to 1 I want the columns to auto unhide. If you could help modify my script to do this I would really appreciate this.

Comment: @Rubén my upvote wont reflext because I have under 15 points. Thank you for informing me, I didn't know!

Comment: 1. If the answer is answering the question (as this is the only answer, you should accept it). 2. If you have a follow-up question you should post a new question.

Comment: 3. If the answer is not answering the question as its currently written and you would like to share more details to help answerers to write a better answer, please, edit your question.

Comment: @coder248 if can you add a online demo , may be i can check and modify script there ?  ,  mean while you can check https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters this link , you need to access data first correctly so checkout other getRange function from the link i shared in answer

Comment: @LogicBlower           [link](https://ibb.co/tM5GRLQ) _italic_ **bold** `code`          Here is what the sheet will look like. I just need the columns with 0 to be hidden and unhidden if it changes to 1.

Comment: check out the script , i added .. and let me know is that what you are looking for  ?